# Line chart with multiple series and irregular intervals not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have multiple series with datetime on x-axis in irregular intervals and with different number of data points. I can't seem to get Highcharts to display these correctly.

The last two data points of "staging" series are incorrectly plotted.

[image: Last two data points of "staging" series are incorrectly plotted]

Full Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vx4ozauf/)

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'line'
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
  },

  subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
      month: '%e. %b',
      year: '%b'
    },
    //      minTickInterval: 3600*100*12,
    //      tickInterval: 3600*100*24

  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Number of Employees'
    },
    min: 0,

  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Installation',
    data: [
      [1526688000000, 100],
      [1526774400000, 150],
      [1526860800000, 200]
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'Staging',
    data: [
      [1526688000000, 130],
      [1526774400000, 170],
      [1526860300000, 230],
      [1526860800000, 280]
    ]
  }],

});
```

Comment: Hi @Sandeep Phadke, Could you add more information about what exactly is dysplayed incorrectly?

Comment: We need more information on what you're trying to achieve. As far as I can tell, the data is being displayed properly.

Comment: You're right @ppotaczek just added an image preview.

Comment: Folks never mind, I was just thrown off by the UNIX timestamp.. you are both correct, they're plotted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As ppotaczek and Phaelax pointed out, the plot is actually working, the millisecond timestamps threw me off.